# Vim syntax highlighting for JSX files stopped working?

Tags: vim, jsx, syntax-highlighting

I closed a vim window completely (something I rarely do) and when I opened it back up my syntax highlighting for jsx files stopped.

I had some other windows open and inside these the syntax highlighting for jsx was still working.

I compared the filetypes in both and could see that the ones that were still working were set to `javascript.jsx` and the exact same files in my new window had a filetype of `javascriptreact`.

Then I shut down all windows to see if reloading all would have an effect, and now all my `.jsx` files come up with filetype of `javascriptreact` with no proper syntax highlighting (especially jsx parts).

I didn't intentionally change any config options that I'm aware of, and am using `vim-jsx` plugin.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on? I am getting the same behavior in terminal Vim and in MacVim.

It's worth noting that when I manually set the filetype back to `javascript.jsx` it doesn't have an effect.

Help!

Comment: Try `:verbose set ft?` to see where the setting is coming from... Does it fix it (for a single file) if you use `:set ft=javascript.jsx` explicitly?

Comment: Vim 8.1.1930 added native support for the `javascriptreact` filetype: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/92852cee3fcff1dc6ce12387b234634e73267b22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrassing, but apparently this line got removed from my `.vimrc`.

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

So none of the plugins in `~/.vim/bundle` were loading. Still not quite sure how that happened, but I suspect carelessness on my part rather than foul play.

Anyway. I survived to code another day...

Comment: why would you suspect chickens? :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas good catch. I've updated it. Some of us aren't native speakers of English. I mean, I am, but some of us aren't. lol